# Copy Items in Outlook Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to copy some items from "Inbox" to "Sent Items\TEMP" in Outlook.  So far I was able to pick up desired messages, based on the subject line, but then I try to copy them with no success.  Where am I going wrong?  Thanks!  Please note, when i do a write-host to retrieve the item I'm looking for, it comes up with no issues, so I am able to retrieve the email with subject line of "Test", but not copy it.

Error message:

> Cannot find an overload for "Copy" and the argument count: "1"

Code:

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application; 

$mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI').GetDefaultFolder(6); 

$mapi2 = $outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI').GetDefaultFolder(5); 
$subFolders2 = $mapi.Folders | ? {$_.FolderPath.EndsWith('TEMP')};

$mapi.Items | ForEach-Object {If ($_.Subject -Like '*TEst*'){$_.Copy($subFolders2)}$_.Save()}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MailItem.Copy does not take any parameters. It returns an instance of the MailItem object; you can then call MailItem.Move and pass the pointer to the destination folder.

Comment: Thank you, @Dmitry.  If I understand you correctly, I am wont be able to Copy these items?  Is there any way to copy the email item from one folder to another based on subject?

Comment: Of course you can - just call Copy (no parameters), then Move(passing the dest. folder).

Comment: Oh, I see.  How then can I word my final copy statement after I do the $_.Copy in Foreach:                                                                 
$mapi.Items | ForEach-Object {If ($_.Subject -Like '*TEst*'){$_.Copy}}

Comment: $_.Copy().Move($subFolders2)